# Is rails 3.0.3 considered edge? what's the latest stable release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is rails 3.0.3 considered edge? what's the latest stable release?

Answer (score 3):

"Edge" is the latest from http://github.com/rails/rails, with 3.0.3 being considered the latest stable release as of this writing.

Edge should not be used for production applications, as it has been known to contain breaking changes. The stable releases on the other hand, contain less (i.e. not 100% bug free, but Good Enough(tm))

Answer (score 0):

3.0.3 is the last stable release.

If I remember correctly:

- 3.0.0 => First stable release of Rails 3
- 3.0.1 => Security Fix
- 3.0.2 => Arel Performance Fix
- 3.0.3 => Arel Performance Fix as well

Comment: 3.0.3 was to fix a bug introduced in 3.0.2.